# Decrypting data on chain and verifying the decryption is correct

Tags: solidity, cryptography, encryption, password

I already know decrypting data on chain will reveal the key and the plaintext to everyone and for my use case that is exactly what I want.

I want to be able to build a contract that has a pre-encrypted message and users have to guess/find the key in order to reveal the message.

My best solution so far is verifying the key is correct by comparing it to a stored hashed key, and then decrypting the message using a encrypt/decrypt function I found on another post (I'm not very good at cryptography)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SecretMessage {
    bytes32 public hashedKey;
    bytes public encryptedMessage;
    address solver;

    constructor (bytes32 _hashedKey, bytes memory _encryptedMessage) {
        hashedKey = _hashedKey;
        encryptedMessage = _encryptedMessage;
    }

    function revealMessage(string memory key) public returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes32 hashed = keccak256(abi.encode(key));
        require(hashed == hashedKey, "Incorrect key!");
        require(solver == address(0), "Already solved!");
        solver = msg.sender;
        return encryptDecrypt(encryptedMessage, abi.encode(key));
    }

    // I dont understand any of this function
    function encryptDecrypt(bytes memory data, bytes memory key)
        public
        pure
        returns (bytes memory result)
    {
        // Store data length on stack for later use
        uint256 length = data.length;

        assembly {
            // Set result to free memory pointer
            result := mload(0x40)
            // Increase free memory pointer by length + 32
            mstore(0x40, add(add(result, length), 32))
            // Set result length
            mstore(result, length)
        }

        // Iterate over the data stepping by 32 bytes
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i += 32) {
            // Generate hash of the key and offset
            bytes32 hash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(key, i));

            bytes32 chunk;
            assembly {
                // Read 32-bytes data chunk
                chunk := mload(add(data, add(i, 32)))
            }
            // XOR the chunk with hash
            chunk ^= hash;
            assembly {
                // Write 32-byte encrypted chunk
                mstore(add(result, add(i, 32)), chunk)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does this have any security risks, such as being able to figure out the key or plaintext with the publicly available information (hashedKey, encryptedMessage)? Is there a better way to decrypt the message and verify the decryption is correct?